# Select value inside a dropdown using ternary operator inside a foreach php loop

Tags: php, mysql

How do you select a dropdown value inside a foreach loop. The code below generate time with 30 minutes gap. I cannot able to select the value from mysql database.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM batches WHERE batch_id = '$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // Name
    echo "<label>Batch name</label> ";
    echo "<input type=text name=name value='".$row['name']."' required> <br />";

    // Start time
    echo "<label>Start time</label> ";
    echo "<select name=starttime value=''> Start time </option>";
        $range = range( strtotime("05:00"), strtotime("21:00"), 30 * 60);
        foreach($range as $time){
            $foo = date("H:i", $time) . "</br>";
            $selected = ($foo == $row['start_time']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
            echo "<option value='$foo'" . $selected . ">" . $foo . "</option>";
        } // foreach
    echo "</select>";

} // while
```

Please help!!

Comment: 'select a dropdown value inside a foreach loop' - what do you mean ?

Comment: @ishegg What do you mean break line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating a break line (`<br>`) to your `$foo` variable, which is why the comparison fails. You don't need this break line inside a `option` tag either, so just get rid of it:

```
foreach($range as $time){
    $foo = date("H:i", $time);
    $selected = ($foo == $row['start_time']) ? 'selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value='$foo'" . $selected . ">" . $foo . "</option>";
} // foreach
```

Also, by your comments, the `start_time` coming from the database contains seconds as well, so you need to format your timestamps accordingly:

```
$foo = date("H:i:s", $time);
```

Comment: It's still not selecting.

Comment: What's in `$row['start_time'];`? It works correctly [here](https://3v4l.org/JUIOF)

Comment: Its a db col_name.

Comment: I know, I'm asking what's in it. What's the result of `var_dump($row['start_time']);`?

Comment: string(8) "10:00:00"

Comment: There's your problem, you need seconds as well. Try `$foo = date("H:i:s", $time);`

Comment: It's no problem :)